# Float Division and implicit round

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

I've found a strange behaviour in a piece of code I wrote which does not happens when I try to reproduce it out of the program (i.e. with MATLAB).

I'm doing a operation over an array as follow:

```
a[i] = a[i] / (sqrt(b[i]) * sqrt(c[i]));
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are arrays of type float. The values of `a`, `b` and `c` prior division range from `2000` to `6000000`

The result of the operation is zero for all the elements of the array, but looking at the values ​​of the numerator and denominator separately, for a given element, the operation is `89509.0 / 90240,375` which is equal to `0,991895258`.

So, I wondering why the full operation within the program using float does not work, and it works separately as expected. Probably due to hours of obfuscated debugging?

Comment: What data type is `a`? `float[]`?

Comment: You haven't given us anywhere close to enough information to help solve your problem. What are the values of `a[i]`, `b[i]`, and `c[i]` prior to the division? *Have you run your program using the debugger?*

Comment: Just guessing, but I suspect that there is a conversion to integer going on here somewhere.

Comment: @slugonamission `a`,`b`,`c` are arrays of floats.

Comment: @DavidHammen be sure i run the debugger before ask in SO. I'm updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I run across a similar situation, I find that it often helps to break it down into steps and see which steps behave properly and which do not. For example, for this, it could be broken down into the following:

```
float sqrtb = sqrt(b[i]);
float sqrtc = sqrt(c[i]);
float divisor = srqtb * sqrtc;
float dividend = a[i];
float quotient = dividend / divisor;
a[i] = quotient;
```

Now I can run through each item and see where it fails (if it fails). Fact is, when I do this, I often find the problem while creating the steps, and then it is fixed.

Comment: Good advice.  Probably what I'd do ,too.

Comment: What surprise that I follow your suggestion and the results are correct, but not when I run the whole operation in a line.

Comment: I'll investigate it further but the truth is that work as you described, which also helped me to confirm intermediate results